# postgresql database server and many users

Tags: database, postgresql, remote-access, remote-server

I'm relatively new to databases - I've used postgresql in the past to create databases stored on my computer and accessed only by myself.

I'm currently designing a database that will be used and edited by multiple people (10-15 max) living in different parts of the world. What is the best way to ensure we will all have access to the most current version of the database? Is it best to continue storing the database on my individual computer? Should I host the database on a cloud server? I've read that it is dangerous to store databases on Dropbox.

We are social science researchers organizing our data into a single database.

Comment: Is your local server always on, have a static IP address, have robust access to the internet, and do you know how to configure your firewall correctly?  Is it at an academic institution, or behind a home ISP?  Whichever one, do they have a policy against you doing this on their connection?  If you host it locally, do you know how to back it up correctly?

Comment: The local server wouldn't always be on or have access to internet. In the past I've created small personal databases on my home ISP but I've never had to make this accessible to others for data entry or querying. Through my research I gathered an individual team member probably shouldn't be hosting the database, I'm just a bit lost because it seems like many of the cloud servers are catering to businesses/apps and we're just trying to set something up for a small team.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment about not always be on and connected, it seems to me that the cloud service is the way to go for you.  There are two approaches there, just rent a machine ("AWS EC2") and install the database software and manage the database yourself, or use a cloud provider's managed database service ("AWS RDS").  The names are just by way of a concrete examples, there are other providers of each type of service.